# Linux C++ userspace app real time sleep function (POSIX, Raspberry Pi)

Tags: c++, linux, raspberry-pi, real-time, sleep

I need a function which suspends my program in µs, it should be real time, so if I call it with 50µs the thread should stop for exactly 50µs.
My C++ program is running on a Raspberry Pi with normal Raspbian installed.

I wrote this example program which uses the posix time functions to suspend an measure the suspend time.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include "stdint-gcc.h"
#include "signal.h"
#include <time.h>
#include <cerrno>
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

#define S_IN_NS 1000000000UL
#define MS_IN_NS 1000000UL
#define US_IN_NS 1000UL
#define GET_TIME_CLOCK CLOCK_MONOTONIC

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    struct timespec newTimeStamp;
    struct timespec oldTimeStamp;
    struct timespec sleeptime;
    sleeptime.tv_sec = 0;
    sleeptime.tv_nsec = 50000; //50us

    if (clock_gettime(GET_TIME_CLOCK, &oldTimeStamp) == -1)
        cout << "Could not get clock time! ERRNO: " << strerror(errno);

    if ((clock_nanosleep(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, 0, &sleeptime, NULL)) == -1)
        cout << "Sleep failed! ERRNO: " << strerror(errno);


    if (clock_gettime(GET_TIME_CLOCK, &newTimeStamp) == -1)
        cout << "Could not get clock time! ERRNO: " << strerror(errno);

    uint64_t measuredSec = (newTimeStamp.tv_sec - oldTimeStamp.tv_sec);
    int32_t measuredNs = (newTimeStamp.tv_nsec - oldTimeStamp.tv_nsec);

    uint64_t diffus = (((measuredSec * S_IN_NS) + measuredNs + 500) / 1000UL);
    uint64_t diffns = (((measuredSec * S_IN_NS) + measuredNs));

    cout << "Diffns:" << diffns << " Diffus:" << diffus << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Build commands:

```
arm-bcm2708hardfp-linux-gnueabi-g++ -lrt   -c -g -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/GNU_ARM_HARDFP-Linux-x86/main.o.d" -o build/Debug/GNU_ARM_HARDFP-Linux-x86/main.o main.cpp

arm-bcm2708hardfp-linux-gnueabi-g++ -lrt    -o dist/Debug/GNU_ARM_HARDFP-Linux-x86/timetest build/Debug/GNU_ARM_HARDFP-Linux-x86/main.o
```

Result (chrt - manipulate real-time attributes of a process):

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo chrt 99 ./timetest 
Diffns:130994 Diffus:131
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo chrt 99 ./timetest 
Diffns:135994 Diffus:136
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo chrt 99 ./timetest 
Diffns:138993 Diffus:139
```

The program should sleep for exactly 50us but I measured 130-139us.
If I change the GET_TIME_CLOCK define to CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID the cpu time (excluding the sleeptime) is measured (So as I understand it).

Result:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo chrt 99 ./timetest 
Diffns:89000 Diffus:89
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo chrt 99 ./timetest 
Diffns:86000 Diffus:86
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo chrt 99 ./timetest 
Diffns:88000 Diffus:88
```

It takes around 80-90µs to do the clock_nanosleep() function, even if I change the sleeptime to 500µs!

So is there any way to suspend a thread for exactly an amount of time (µs) in a C++ userspace application on Raspbian?

thx

Comment: Can you explain why you need such function? Cause usually there's almost always a better solution than suspending for an exact amount of time..

Comment: CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID  measures time your program spends on the CPU. Your program will use the same amount of CPU no matter how long you sleep (since sleeping doesn't use CPU time). You may get more acurate results with `chrt -f 1 ./timetest`, but in general you'll need a real time OS to avoid too much jittering.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to sleep for such a precise amount of time, you probably need to use a spin loop with a check of the current time.  This will consume rather a lot of power (and generate heat), but it's a fairly reliable and portable way to do it.  Another idea is to try the ideas on this page: http://blog.regehr.org/archives/794